# Check if values exist

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm writing a webscraper that looks for `<td>` rows in a HTML table:

```
# open CSV with URLS to scrape
csv_file = csv.reader(open('urls.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')

names = []
for data in csv_file:
    names.append(data[0])

for name in names:
   html = D.get(name);
   html2 = html
   param = '<br />';
   html2 = html2.replace("<br />", " | ")
   print name

   c = csv.writer(open("darkgrey.csv", "a"))
   for row in xpath.search(html2, '//table/tr[@class="bgdarkgrey"]'):
       cols = xpath.search(row, '/td')
       c.writerow([cols[0], cols[1], cols[2], cols[3], cols[4]])
```

All it does is get values from 4 table `'<td>'`

The problem is, some of the tables don't have `cols[2]`, `cols[3]` or `cols[4]`

Is there a way, that I can check if these exist?

Thanks

Comment: bit offtopic, but do you really want to append to "darkgrey.csv"? If I where you I would open that file in global scope with "w" to prevent it growing to inf when you test this script over again. Also make sure to close it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely familiar with `xpath`, but you should be able to just check the length of `cols` (as long as it isn't a really strange object that looks like a sequence in other ways):

```
 if len(cols) >= 5:
    ...
```

Another common python idiom is to just try it and see.

```
try:
    c.writerow([cols[0], cols[1], cols[2], cols[3], cols[4]])
except IndexError:
    #failed because `cols` isn't long enough.  Do something else.
```

Finally, assuming `cols` is a `list`, you can always make sure that it is long enough:

```
cols.extend(['']*5)
```

which will pad your columns with empty strings so that you have *at least 5 columns* (usually more).

Comment: Brilliant!! I ran the first part and it seems to work. I've not used Python before, so its all a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

```
c.writerow([col[x] for x in range(0,len(col))])
```

also dont forget to close the "darkgrey.csv" file!

Comment: Maybe easier:  `col[:5]` -- Slicing sequences is forgiving :)

Comment: wow, tested that and it is indeed really forgiving. Learned something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way of doing this

```
c.writerow([cols[0], cols[1], '' if not(cols[2]) else cols[2], '' if not(cols[3]) else cols[3], '' if not(cols[4]) else cols[4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to say `cols = xpath.search(row, 'td')` not `cols = xpath.search(row, '/td')`? (without slash)